# WordPress custom field images not getting inserted into array

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Wordpress to create a dynamic gallery using Bootstrap. I created a new custom field and then set it to 'images' and then assigned it to my post type. It then shows up in my post, I uploaded my images into the field and then attempt to put all the attachments into an array and then i will loop through them to display.

```
$args = array(
'post-type' => 'attachment',
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_status' => 'any',
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
'exclude' => get_post_thumbnail_id()
);

$attachments = get_posts($args);
```

After doing this and doing a var dump with attachments, it says that nothing is in the array

Comment: Have you used ACF for uploading image into custom field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to display the custom field values inside a post you have to use `<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'custom-field-name',true) ?>` inside the posts display loop.

Comment: If I was going to use with this with bootstraps carousal I wouldn't use the loop, is there still a way of implementing this?

Comment: I've done this but not its using all of my images at once, is there a way to only display one image at a time?